# how to add ember and ember cli to azure website or cload service for ember projects

Tags: azure, ember.js, express, deployment, ember-cli

I want to use Azure for my Ember project. my project uses `Ember.js` and `ember-cli`, I can not see it on azure same html websites. for `angular.js` project, I have added some script code in `deploy.cmd`. but i don't know what should i add to `deploy.cmd` to run `ember.js` and `ember-cli` . All samples in internet use some script in `deploy.sh` and I don't know about its syntax. can u help me please?

Answer (score 0):

We at Microsoft actually wrote a small npm module to help you with that. You can find it at https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-azure-deploy.

Short version: Run this in your project.

`npm install --save-dev -g ember-cli-azure-deploy
azure-deploy init`